# mysql replication in windows os not working

Tags: mysql, replication

I have tried master - slave two way replication. (I installed mysql through xampp and navicat lite).Master slave configuration settings have done.master.Show master status and Show slave status are success in my master system. But Slave status showing some following error  in my slave machine.   Slave_IO_Running: No and  Last_IO_Error: error

mysql> show slave status\G
 1. row 
               Slave_IO_State:
                  Master_Host: 10.10.3.128
                  Master_User: slaveuser
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000002
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 3201
               Relay_Log_File: mysqld-relay-bin.000002
                Relay_Log_Pos: 149
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000002
             **Slave_IO_Running: No**
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB:
          Replicate_Ignore_DB:
           Replicate_Do_Table:
       Replicate_Ignore_Table:
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error:
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 3201
              Relay_Log_Space: 305
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File:
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File:
           Master_SSL_CA_Path:
              Master_SSL_Cert:
            Master_SSL_Cipher:
               Master_SSL_Key:
        Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 1045
                **Last_IO_Error: error connecting to master 'test@10.10.3.128:3306**
' - retry-time: 60  retries: 86400
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error:
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: Off topic, try superuser or dba.

Answer (score 1):

Check admin privilege and please ensure that no firewall blocks.